# FileReader cannot find file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, filereader, filewriter

I have a text file which includes the dictionary for the program below.
For some reason "Word.txt" cannot be found even its on file extension on eclipse which
I also tried doing on notepad but I got none. Hope someone can help me with this thanks.

Word.txt file contains:

```
algebra<===>a generalization of arithmetic in which letters representing numbers are combined according to the rules of arithmetic
book<===>a set of written sheets of skin or paper or tablets of wood or ivory
calculus<===>the mathematical methods comprising differential and integral calculus
data<===>factual information such as a basis for reasoning, discussion, or calculation
grammar<===>a system of rules that defines the grammatical structure of a language
information<===>knowledge obtained from investigation, study, or instruction
language<===>the words, their pronunciation, and the methods of combining them used and understood by a community
laptop<===>a portable microcomputer having its main components (such as processor keyboard, and display screen) integrated into a single unit capable of battery-powered operation
metadata<===>data that provides information about other data
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Word.txt 
   (The system cannot find the file specified)

    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at PL1.main(PL1.java:18)
```

CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PL1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("Word.txt");
        FileReader R = new FileReader("Word.txt");
        BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(R);
        BufferedReader In = null;
        In = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Word.txt"));
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
        int choices;
        int number;
        int x = 1;
        String s = "";
        String read = null;

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("--------------SELECT FROM THE CHOICES--------------");
                System.out.println("1 - Show all records");
                System.out.println("2 - Search for definition");
                System.out.println("3 - Add record");
                System.out.println("4 - Delete record");
                System.out.println("5 - Delete all records");
                System.out.println("6 - Exit");
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
                choices = input.nextInt();
                switch (choices) {
                    case 1: 
                        x = 1;
                        System.out.println("--------------------ALL RECORDS--------------------");

                        try {
                            while ((read = In.readLine()) != null) {
                                String[] splitted = read.split("<===>");
                                for (String part : splitted) {
                                    System.out.print(x++ + ". " + part + "\t \n");
                                }
                            }

                            System.out.println("< Records found: " + x / 2 + " >");

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        String searchword;
                        System.out.println("-------------------SEARCH RECORD-------------------");
                        System.out.println("Word:");
                        searchword = input.nextLine();

                        try {
                            while ((s = Br.readLine()) != null) {
                                String[] splitted = s.split("<===>");
                                number = splitted.length;
                                for (int e = 0; e < splitted.length; e += 2) {
                                    for (int j = 1; j < splitted.length; j += 2) {
                                        if (splitted[e].equals(searchword)) {
                                            splitted[e] = splitted[j];
                                            System.out.println("-" + splitted[e]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        String word;
                        String definition;
                        System.out.println("--------------------ADD RECORD--------------------");
                        System.out.println("Word:");
                        word = input.nextLine();
                        word = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Definition:");
                        definition = input.nextLine();

                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Word.txt", true);
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);
                        out.print(" \n" + word + "<===>" + definition);
                        out.close();
                        System.out.println("< Record has been saved successfully. >");
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        System.out.println("Thank You!");
                        return;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                        break;
                }
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full path to file `Word.txt`?

Comment: I putted it on desktop and on resources

Comment: I didn't ask where you put the file, I asked what the full path is. Are you saying that there are two files named `Word.txt` in two different folders? The path to `Desktop` folder is `C:\Users\USER\Desktop` where `USER` is your user name. Assuming your user name is `Francis`, the path would be `C:\Users\Francis\Desktop` which means the path to the file would be `C:\Users\Francis\Desktop\Word.txt`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your file path. If your file is inside any package (like src or something similar) of your project or it is outside your project folder then IOException will be thrown. In such cases you need to provide full path into FileReader

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/user/demo-project/src/word.txt")
```

or

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/user/desktop/word.txt")
```

If you don't want to pass full file path then you have to place your file direct inside your project folder.

Refer below image link:
[FileReader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ygz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not giving the program the entire path to this "Word.txt", ie: let's say the file is on your desktop then you should do something like:

```
FileReader R = new FileReader("C\YourUser\Desktop\Word.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem here is that your path.
If `Word.txt` is inside src folder then you have to say like it:-
`FileReader reader = new FileReader("src\\if any another folder\\Word.txt");`
If it is just outside src folder then you can use `Word.txt` as path
If path is totally different, then just write full path there